# referencing static methods from class variable

Tags: python, static-methods, class-variables

I know it's wired to have such a case but somehow I have it:

```
class foo
  #static method
  @staticmethod
  def test():
    pass

  # class variable
  c = {'name' : <i want to reference test method here.>}
```

What's the way to it?

**Just for the record:**

**I believe this should be considered as python worst practices. Using static methods is not really pythoish way if ever...**

Comment: You should consider using new-style classes if possible.

Comment: Also, note that `staticmethod` should not usually be used. Python has normal functions for this application.

Comment: that's still not syntactically-valid python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Foo:
    # static method
    @staticmethod
    def test():
        pass

    # class variable
    c = {'name' : test }
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is static methods in python are descriptor objects. So in the following code:

```
class Foo:
    # static method
    @staticmethod
    def test():
        pass

    # class variable
    c = {'name' : test }
```

`Foo.c['name']` is the descriptor object, thus is not callable. You would have to type `Foo.c['name'].__get__(None, Foo)()` to correctly call `test()` here. If you're unfamiliar with descriptors in python, have a look at [the glossary](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-descriptor), and there's plenty of docs on the web. Also, have a look at [this thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-August/272596.html), which seems to be close to your use-case.

To keep things simple, you could probably create that `c` class attribute just outside of the class definition:

```
class Foo(object):
  @staticmethod
  def test():
    pass

Foo.c = {'name': Foo.test}
```

or, if you feel like it, dive in the documentation of [`__metaclass__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation).