# How to reference static method from class variable

Tags: python, decorator, static-methods, class-variables, python-typing

Given the class

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import ClassVar, Dict, Final
import abc

class Cipher(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def encrypt(self, plaintext: str) -> str:
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def decrypt(self, ciphertext: str) -> str:
        pass

class VigenereCipher(Cipher):
    @staticmethod
    def rotate(n: int) -> str:
        return string.ascii_uppercase[n:] + string.ascii_uppercase[:n]

    _TABLE: Final[ClassVar[Dict[str, str]]] = dict({(chr(i + ord("A")), rotate(i)) for i in range(26)})
```

Compilation fails (**using 3.8.0**)

```
../cipher.py:19: in <module>
    class VigenereCipher(Cipher):
../cipher.py:24: in VigenereCipher
    _TABLE: Final[ClassVar[Dict[str, str]]] = dict({(chr(i + ord("A")), rotate(i)) for i in range(26)})
../cipher.py:24: in <setcomp>
    _TABLE: Final[ClassVar[Dict[str, str]]] = dict({(chr(i + ord("A")), rotate(i)) for i in range(26)})
E   NameError: name 'rotate' is not defined
```

However, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2194185/839733) post, `rotate` should be resolvable. Note that qualifying with class name `VigenereCipher` doesn't work either since it can't find `VigenereCipher` (makes sense, since we are in the process of defining it).

I can make `rotate` a module-level method, and that works, but I don't really want to since it only is needed in `VigenereCipher`.

Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12718272/839733) answer with no success.

Actual code is [here](https://github.com/asarkar/python3-bootcamp/blob/master/sec-14/capstone/text/cipher.py). Unit test is [here](https://github.com/asarkar/python3-bootcamp/blob/master/sec-14/capstone/text/test/test_cipher.py).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204823/discussion-on-question-by-abhijit-sarkar-how-to-reference-static-method-from-cla).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is raised from here:

```
_TABLE: Final[ClassVar[Dict[str, str]]] = dict({(chr(i + ord("A")), rotate(i)) for i in range(26)})
```

You are trying to refer the variable `rotate` that is located in class namespace. However python comprehensions have their own scope and there is no simple way to connect it with class namespace. There is no closure or global variable `rotate` at the moment of comprehension evaluation - thus `NameError` is invoked. The code above is equal to your code:

```
def _create_TABLE():
    d = {}
    for i in range(26):
        d[chr(i + ord("A"))] = rotate(i) # -> NameError('rotate')
    return d
_TABLE: Final[ClassVar[Dict[str, str]]] = dict(_create_TABLE())
del _create_TABLE
```

> How to reference static method from class variable

A class variable in python is some object, so it can refer to any objects in your program. Here some idioms you can follow:

Approach 1:

```
class VigenereCipher(Cipher):
    @staticmethod
    def rotate(n: int) -> str:
        return string.ascii_uppercase[n:] + string.ascii_uppercase[:n]

    _TABLE: Final[ClassVar[Dict[str, str]]]

VigenereCipher._TABLE = {chr(i + ord("A")): VigenereCipher.rotate(i) for i in range(26)}
```

Approach 2:

```
class VigenereCipher(Cipher):
    @staticmethod
    def rotate(n: int) -> str:
        return string.ascii_uppercase[n:] + string.ascii_uppercase[:n]

    _TABLE: Final[ClassVar[Dict[str, str]]] = (
        lambda r=rotate.__func__: {chr(i + ord("A")): r(i) for i in range(26)})()
```

Approach 3:

```
class VigenereCipher(Cipher):
    @staticmethod
    def rotate(n: int) -> str:
        return string.ascii_uppercase[n:] + string.ascii_uppercase[:n]

    _TABLE: Final[ClassVar[Dict[str, str]]] = dict(zip(
        (chr(i + ord("A")) for i in range(26)),
        map(rotate.__func__, range(26)),
    ))
```

Approach 4:

```
class VigenereCipher(Cipher):
    @staticmethod
    def rotate(n: int) -> str:
        return string.ascii_uppercase[n:] + string.ascii_uppercase[:n]

    _TABLE: Final[ClassVar[Dict[str, str]]] = {
        chr(i + ord("A")): r(i) for r in (rotate.__func__,) for i in range(26)}
```

There are also approaches based on:

- [`locals` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals);
- [metaclasses](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/);
- [`__init__subclass__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__init_subclass__);
- [descriptor's `__set_name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__);
- [stack frames](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys._getframe);
- using `global` keyword.

You can find a more detailed answers in the related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905741/accessing-class-variables-from-a-list-comprehension-in-the-class-definition)

Comment: Creating a method and deleting it seems like a giant hack. Also, in your code, is `rotate` still a static method?

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar i've just rewrite **your code** in a more understandable way - the mistake is still here

Comment: I'm not following, what mistake would that be? I'm not asking for a code review here, so if you simply rewrote the code without addressing the issue, that's no help.

Comment: This is likely to fail any type checking, e.g. `Final` types should be initialized on definition. And should be not be redefined.

Comment: This works but as @AChampion said, it's flies in the face of `Final`. It works though because, I quote from the docs, "_There is no runtime checking of these properties._". Too bad, static typing in Python is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar version 2 was added

Comment: Fails with `'function' object has no attribute '__func__'`. It appears you're just throwing spaghetti at the wall without actually verifying the code you're proposing. You should be downvoted.

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar, `rotate` **is not a function**. It is a **staticmethod** after the `@staticmethod` applied. I just checked the functionality of my is code - **everything is fine**. Moreover, you can see the accepted answer in a related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13913933/12412188) and see the simular solution there.

Comment: I always check what I post. And it looks that you are unable to check it impartially

Comment: OK, after some tweedling, this code does work. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Why does this look like a hack of a solution?